# PHP preg_match_all fails on long strings

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
$long = str_repeat('a very long string text', 100); // try changing 100 to 5000

$str = <<<STR
<abc>a short string text</abc>
<abc>$long</abc>
STR;

preg_match_all('@<abc>([^<>]+)</abc>@sU', $str, $matched);

print_r($matched);
```

And it works totally as expected. However, after you have changed 100 repetitions to 5000, run

```
print_r($matched);
```

And you will only get results for the short string occurrence.

My question is how to make preg_match or preg_match_all to work with large string texts (as large as 1MB or larger)?

Comment: Looks like you try to parse HTML/XML with regex.
Don't do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 for the reasons why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably need to increase the PCRE limits.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php

Edit: But yeah, as ThiefMaster says, don't do this.

Comment: These parameters are named `pcre.backtrack_limit` and `pcre.recursion_limit` and placed in php.ini.

Comment: It would be nice if the manual pages on the PCRE functions (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) would say, under "Parameters > `subject`", that if `subject` is longer than these limits, the result will be an error (i.e., return `false`), but not an exception that can be caught.