# PHP preg_match_all not working on large data

Tags: php, laravel

Why is `preg_match_all` not working?

`$pattern = '/\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}/';`

`$result = 161240` characters

```
       if (preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches)) {
            echo 'Success';
        } else {
            echo 'Not working';
        }
```

This Displays: "Not working"

Comment: Did you check the type of encoding? If there are spaces they will be considered "other character". More, we need the pattern to understand what is going on.

Comment: Here's the pattern $pattern = '/\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}/';

Comment: it work if the character length is lower than 500.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180910/php-preg-match-all-fails-on-long-strings,: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315879/php-preg-match-all-100-mb-file

Comment: @pradeep thanks. i saw that already but is there a way to change it to htaccess?

Comment: Try to set a php configuration option like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296441/maximum-length-of-string-preg-match-all-can-match-and-acquire

Comment: What if `preg_match_all` returns `0` which means nothing found. It returns `FALSE` if it fails.

Comment: `if (preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches) === FALSE){/* FAILED */}`

Comment: @MarkD you know what this pattern is doing?

Comment: @wp78de actually i use this to get the value of curl_exec to encode it to json data

Comment: @MarkD the subject `$result` is too long, try to cut it, and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern at play matches balanced curly brackets using regex recursion. The pattern itself looks fine and works as [intended](https://regex101.com/r/NeOz8I/1).

```
<?php
$re = '/{(?>[^{}]|(?R))*\}/m';
$str = 'Why is preg_match_all not working?{{{{{
$pattern = \'/\\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\\}/\';
$result = 161240 characters
       if (preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches)){ {
            echo \'Success\';
        } else {
            echo \'Not working\';
        }
}}}}}}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{{{{{{}}}}}';

//preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
echo 'Success\n';
} else {
echo 'Not working\n';
}

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

This also works with larger input (here [tested](https://ideone.com/BI7NLd) with ~5000 characters).
The most likely explanation is: the pattern does not find a valid match.

However, you are running a recursive regex on a very large input string. Many, things could go wrong. The PCRE engine reaches internal limits, your string is not properly encoded, timeouts, etc.